# connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080 POST /api/abc/abc 500 61 - 461.363 ms

Tags: python, node.js, fastapi

I am trying to make a call from node.js to fastapi and while making a call I see the error `connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080 POST /api/abc/abc 500 61 - 461.363 ms`.
I am trying to send data from my node endpoint to the fastapi end point but the error seems to stop the data being sent to the fastapi endpoint as I don't see any post request on fastapi as the request never gets satisfied from the node.js endpoint.

I am trying to make a call from node.js to fastapi and while making a call I see the error `connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080 POST /api/abc/abc 500 61 - 461.363 ms`.
I've been trying to brute force all the ways in which I can define the path have not only tried writing localhost but also 127.0.0.1. Moreover, I did try to run fastapi server on another port just to be sure but even that seems to not solve the problem. Please help.